# When fighting Shalltear, why would Ainz use Body of Effulgent Beryl?

Tags: overlord

Why would Ainz use Body of Effulgent Beryl (which [According to the Wiki](https://overlordmaruyama.fandom.com/wiki/Ainz_Ooal_Gown/Abilities_and_Powers) reduces the effectiveness of bludgeoning attacks) as his defensive spell when fighting Shalltear as opposed to a spell that reduces *piercing* damage? Such as Body of Effulgent Aquamarine. Given the weapon she is using, it seems it would deal piercing damage as opposed to bludgeoning damage.

This seems especially true in this screenshot where her pipette lance clearly *pierces* him.
[image]

Comment: Small disclaimer, I'm posting this from work and I can't actually view the wiki myself, the information I have was from a google cached copy of a Reddit post.

Comment: The wiki doesn't list Body of Effulgent Aquamarine as one of Ainz's skills, so maybe he can't use that and Body of Effulgent Beryl was at least something?

Comment: As skeleton does piercing damage even work? Blunt damage is a major weakness for skeletons in most games.
maybe every weapon has a certain amount of damage in everything and he needed to remove the blunt damage only because it is the only damage that would affect him greatly. before we have seen that his body being pierced by an angelic light sword and iron short swords is not very effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to volume 3 of the light novel, the lance does "battering"(i.e. bludgeoning) damage in Chapter 5. Which is why Ainz used it.

> The tenth-tier spell Body of Effulgent Beryl, in addition to decreasing damage taken by battering weapons for its duration, allow onetime full immunity to the damage. By having Body of Effulgent Beryl absorb the damage from the lance, its tip moved out of his body as if time had been rewound.

This explicitly states that Shalltear's weapon does bludgeoning damage and it as absorbed by the spell.

As a side note undead races have a racial vulnerability to bludgeoning damage (Bludgeoning Vulnerability V).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!